# Is there an infinite Duration in Java 8 equivalent to the .NET Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan Field?

Tags: java, c#, timespan, infinite, duration

Everything is in the title:
Is there an infinite Duration in Java 8 equivalent to the C# Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan Field?

A bit like:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinitetimespan(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't think -1 ms is understood across the all java libraries as an infinite timespan, so it might be more a problem of definition.

In order to clarify a bit the context, let's say I want to make a thread asleep for an infinite amount of time without performing an infinite loop, note that this not necessarily a realistic practical use though.

I'm just wondering is there anything built-in in the Java libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Duration` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

> A physical duration could be of infinite length. For practicality, the duration is stored with constraints similar to Instant. The duration uses nanosecond resolution with a maximum value of the seconds that can be held in a long. This is greater than the current estimated age of the universe.

You certainly don't need to do an infinite loop to suspend a thread.  Consider `LockSupport.park()` or another one of the many available mechanisms in `java.util.concurrent`.  Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: Well I see, actually it was more a question out of curiosity.
I was just wondering whether there is certain value which is considered in the Java "standard" libraries as an infinite Duration in Java, a bit similar to the Infinite TimeSpan in .NET which is actually -1 ms.
Another solution is also to use the biggest value of a long when defining a Duration.
And true, I just can just go with a LockSupport.Park(); call for suspending a thread.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

As an extension to [@Misha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32708159/6346531), this is essentially the largest duration value allowed:

```java
public static final Duration MAX_DURATION = Duration.ofSeconds(
        Long.MAX_VALUE,   // Max allowed seconds
        999999999L        // Max nanoseconds less than a second
);
```

Anything more than this leads to

```plaintext
java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
```